# Displaying values from a list of objects (within a list of objects)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an List of *Post* Objects

```
 List<Post> p = new List<Post>();
```

**Constructor for POST**

```
 public Post(int postID, string title, DateTime date, string body, List<Comment> comments)
    {
        this.postID = postID;
        this.title = title;
        this.date = date;
        this.body = body;
        this.comments = comments;
    }
```

As you can see in the constructor the list of *Posts* contain a list of comments.

**Constructor for COMMENTS**

```
public Comment(int commentId, DateTime date, string body) 
    {
        this.commentID = commentID;
        this.date = date;
        this.body = body;
    }
```

My problem is displaying these comments in my page.aspx

**Page.aspx**

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repeater1" ItemType="OOPBLOG.Model.Classes.Post" 
    SelectMethod="LoadPosts"
    OnCallingDataMethods="postView">

    <ItemTemplate>
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td><%#Item.Title %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><%#Item.Body %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><%#Item.Date %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><%#Item.comment[0].Body%>></td>
        </tr>          
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
```

As you can see at the moment if displaying only the first comment of the list, how would i go about using foreach or for loop to display all comments?

Btw, i using model binding and webforms.

Comment: You would need another repeater nested inside of this one.  The outer repeater shows all of the posts, the inner repeater shows all of the comments for a particular post.

Comment: Would i be able to use the same data in the 2nd repeater? or do i have make another call to my model? please give an example of how it should look like. .

Comment: It's been a *long* time since I've used WebForms, so I'm afraid the specifics of implementing this are unfamiliar to me.  (Mostly the semantics of how it uses model binding these days.)  But you should be able to find some examples of nested repeaters online somewhere.  It absolutely *should* use the same in-memory object, I just don't know the syntax to make that happen.